# how to accept a socket without setting a thread on it in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

How can I create a server which accept entered sockets and than enter them into a queue (wihout setting a thread on each one of them)?

here is a code of regular multithread (here you create thread per a socket, but I want that each socket which I accept, will enter the queue, without creating thread per a socket):

```
public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable{

    int          serverPort   = 10000;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    public MultiThreadedServer(int port){
        this.serverPort = port;
    }

    public void run(){

         try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 10000", e);
        }
        while(true){
            Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error accepting client connection", e);
            }
            new Thread(new WorkerRunnable( clientSocket, "Multithreaded Server")).start();
        }
    }
```

thank you

Comment: See the part where you create a `Thread`? Replace it with a part that puts the socket in a queue.

Comment: Try Java NIO, in which you can do multiplexed (and non-blocking) io. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29

Comment: @Kayaman, the creation of the new thread is happening in the same time as the acceptence of the sockets?

what will happen if i will create thread when a socket request arrive?

Comment: @adi It ***isn't*** 'happening at the same time as the acceptance of the socket'. It can't. `accept()` doesn't create a thread. 'What will happen if I will create a thread when a socket request arrives' is that a thread will be created. Your question doesn't make sense, and the last one is merely tautogical.

Comment: I dont understand, shouldn't I create a new thread which will be created in every time that a socket arrive, like that:                                                                     
`while(true){
           Socket clientSocket = null;
            try {
             clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            } .....
            Thread t1 = new Thread(){
      public void run(){
                         queue.add(clientSocket);}
        }`
thread1 will die right after it adds the socket to the queue

Comment: You would create a thread if it is actually doing to do something, especailly blocking I/O, but why would you create a thread just to add a socket to a queue?. What's the question here?

Answer (score 1):

This code should accomplish what you want, if I understand your question correctly.

```
public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable
{

    int serverPort = 10000;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    ArrayList<Socket> socketQueue;  //ArrayList to be used as a queue

    public MultiThreadedServer(int port)
    {
        this.serverPort = port;

        socketQueue = new ArrayList<>();    //Initialize your ArrayList
    }

    public void run()
    {
         try 
        {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        } 

         catch (IOException e) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open port 10000", e);
        }

         while(true)
         {
            Socket clientSocket = null;

            try 
            {
                clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
            }

            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error accepting client connection", e);
            }

            socketQueue.add(clientSocket);  //Add your newly accepted socket to ArrayList
            //new Thread(new WorkerRunnable( clientSocket, "Multithreaded Server")).start();
        }
   }
}
```

Every time a new connection is accepted, it will be added to socketQueue (ArrayList).